# sum of $p$th roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, finite-fields, roots-of-unity, exponential-sum

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Let $\mathbb Z_p$ be the ring of integers from $0$ to $p-1$, i.e. $\mathbb Z_p=\left\{0,1,\dots,p-1\right\}$. Let $r$ be a positive integer. Then, for all values of $p$, is the following sum equals to 1?

$$\sum_{x \in \mathbb Z_p}e^{\pi irx^2/p}$$

I have shown it is true for $p=3,5$.

In addition, does it make any difference for the answer that if we know $r$ is even or odd?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum

Comment: Your sums are certainly not equal to $1$ for $p=3,5$ if $r=2$. Your sums are called Gauss sums, but are slightly different from the simplest case because there is just $\pi i$ instead of $2\pi i$ in the numerator. (If $2$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ though these cases are the same, and similarly for fixed $p$ the sum only depends on whether or not $r$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$.)

Comment: @user8268 In the web site the given sum has $2\pi i$ in the numerator. SO, it is a little different from mine...

Comment: @anon So, then could you please write the answer of the sum?

Comment: I don't see how you could get this to sum to one? As you talk about $\Bbb{Z}_p$, I assume that you calculate $rx^2$ in that field. Then all the terms have non-negative imaginary parts and the sum will have positive imaginary part. If you don't compute $rx^2$ in $\Bbb{Z}_p$, then I don't understand why you mention $\Bbb{Z}_p$ in the first place.

Comment: Sorry about being a bit impolite last night. Surely you simply mean to study the sums
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}e^{\pi i r k^2/p}$$ with all the arithmetic done with integers. It is one of my pet peeves, when programmers think that $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is just a shorthand for the set $\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$ when it really means the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ together with the consequence that all the arithmetic is done modulo $p$ without any separate notice (or in more advanced contexts the ring of $p$-adic integers). Anyway, as anon said you do get Gauss sums when $r$ is even. Also $r=2p$ gives sum $p$.

Comment: We can think $ \sum_{x \in \mathbb Z_p}e^{\pi irk^2/p}=\sum_{x \in \mathbb Z_p}e^{2\pi irk^2/2p}$ and then have a solution according to the referance that user8268 has given previously. $r$ being odd or even does not change anything as $r/2$ mod p is well defined. Thanks for the comments